# WebClient для Golang

Tags: javascript, парсер, golang

В природе существует какой-то **WebClient**, который поддерживает исполнение js-кода в html-странице?
Задача в том, что нужно спарсить **DOM** страницы сайта, но страница собирается js-кодом (SPA).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел в итоге отличную библиотеку для парсинга: https://github.com/geziyor/geziyor
Исполняет, в том числе, js-код на страницы с помощью chrome-движка (нужно тоже установить будет).

Comment: Вроде пакет установился, а дальше что делать?